# Which is the second resistor in a voltage divider?

Tags: electric-circuits, electrical-resistance, voltage

The formula for a voltage divider is:

Voltage out = ( resistance two/resistance one + resistance two ) * voltage in

or Vo = ( R2 / R1 + R2 ) * Vi

How do you identify the R1 resistor? Is it the one which conventional current 'goes through' first?

Comment: you just choose which one you want to know the voltage over. Typically this is the one over which your load is connected in parallel.

Comment: Why the down vote? What is wrong about this question?

Comment: it wasn't my dv.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The voltage divider formula is used where there is a series of two resistor and you want to know the voltage through one of the two.
The voltage drop of the resistor number 1 is 
$$
V_1 = V_i \frac{R_1}{R_1 + R_2}
$$

The voltage drop of the resistor number 2 is:
$$
V_2 = V_i \frac{R_2}{R_1 + R_2}
$$